# MongoDB database db.collection.find returns results but meteor-angular pub/sub nor collection.find does not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor

In meteor I have:

```
var data_set = elephant_site_service_calcs_ts.find(
                        {
                            calc_tag_id: parseInt(calc.alert_id),
                            calc_ts_update_hour: start_date
                        });
console.log(data_set.fetch());
```

In an autorun. For testing I also have:

```
var calc_tag_data =  $meteor.collection(elephant_site_service_calcs_ts)
                        .subscribe('site_calcs_realtime',{
                            calc_ts_update_hour: 1,
                            calc_tag_id: 1,
                            values: 1
                        },
                        {
                            calc_tag_id: parseInt(calc.alert_id),
                            calc_ts_update_hour:
                            {
                                $gt:  start_date.toString()
                            }

                        });
console.log("Calc time series data " + calc_tag_data);
```

When I run either of them directly against MongoDB I get:

```
elephant_data_replicaset:PRIMARY> db.elephant_calc_evalv_ts.find(
...     {
...             calc_tag_id: 138,
...             calc_ts_update_hour:
...             {
...                 $gt:  '2015-08-24 15:00:00'
...             }
...
...     },
...     {
...         calc_ts_update_hour: 1,
...         calc_tag_id: 1,
...         values: 1
...     });

{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dba62a71aad4b469c2dcd7"), "calc_tag_id" : 138,     "calc_ts_update_hour" : "2015-08-24 16:00:00", "values" : { "18" : { "2" : 0.00011940298507462686 }, "53" : { "22" : 0.00011940298507462686 } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dbb8a571aad4b469c2dce6"), "calc_tag_id" : 138, "calc_ts_update_hour" : "2015-08-24 17:00:00", "values" : { "36" : { "53" : 0.00011940298507462686 } } }

elephant_data_replicaset:PRIMARY> db.elephant_calc_evalv_ts.find(     {              calc_tag_id: 138,             calc_ts_update_hour:             {                 $gt:  '2015-08-24 15:00:00'             }      },     {         calc_ts_update_hour: 1,         calc_tag_id: 1,         values: 1     });
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dba62a71aad4b469c2dcd7"), "calc_tag_id" : 138, "calc_ts_update_hour" : "2015-08-24 16:00:00", "values" : { "18" : { "2" : 0.00011940298507462686 }, "53" : { "22" : 0.00011940298507462686 } } }
 { "_id" : ObjectId("55dbb8a571aad4b469c2dce6"), "calc_tag_id" : 138, "calc_ts_update_hour" : "2015-08-24 17:00:00", "values" : { "36" : { "53" : 0.00011940298507462686 } } }
elephant_data_replicaset:PRIMARY> cls
elephant_data_replicaset:PRIMARY> db.elephant_calc_evalv_ts.find(     {                calc_tag_id: 138,             calc_ts_update_hour:             {                   $gt:  '2015-08-24 15:00:00'             }      },     {            calc_ts_update_hour: 1,         calc_tag_id: 1,         values: 1     });
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dba62a71aad4b469c2dcd7"), "calc_tag_id" : 138, "calc_ts_update_hour" : "2015-08-24 16:00:00", "values" : { "18" : { "2" : 0.00011940298507462686 }, "53" : { "22" : 0.00011940298507462686 } } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55dbb8a571aad4b469c2dce6"), "calc_tag_id" : 138,   "calc_ts_update_hour" : "2015-08-24 17:00:00", "values" : { "36" : { "53" : 0.00011940298507462686 } } }
elephant_data_replicaset:PRIMARY> db.elephant_calc_evalv_ts.find(     {             calc_tag_id: 138,             calc_ts_update_hour:  '2015-08-24 15:00:00' },     {         calc_ts_update_hour: 1,         calc_tag_id: 1,         values: 1     });
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55db93fc71aad4b469c2dcc6"), "calc_tag_id" : 138, "calc_ts_update_hour" : "2015-08-24 15:00:00", "values" : { "0" : { "28" : 0.00011940298507462686 }, "10" : { "16" : 0.00011940298507462686 }, "19" : { "2" : 0.00011940298507462686 }, "30" : { "53" : 0.00011940298507462686 } } }
elephant_data_replicaset:PRIMARY>
```

But when run through meteor I get:

```
Getting calc current value from time series data: 133
elephantTopicListCtrl.js?f5170d3f444b49f17026653cb5c451bda922d0e3:120 Data hour: 2015-08-24 15:00:00 data minute: 52 for calc_id 133
elephantTopicListCtrl.js?f5170d3f444b49f17026653cb5c451bda922d0e3:129 []
elephantTopicListCtrl.js?f5170d3f444b49f17026653cb5c451bda922d0e3:146 Calc time series data 
elephantTopicListCtrl.js?f5170d3f444b49f17026653cb5c451bda922d0e3:294 Processing calc dataset
```

Pretty much an empty dataset. On the server publish routine I have:

```
Meteor.publish("site_calcs_realtime", function(options, searchString) {
console.log("Calcs realtime");
console.log(searchString);
console.log(options);

if(searchString == null)
    searchString = {};

//Get real time data for the past hour for tags
//console.log(elephant_site_service_calcs_ts.find(searchString, options));
return elephant_site_service_calcs_ts.find(searchString, options);
});
```

The output from the meteor command line:

```
I20150824-20:04:30.236(-7)? Calcs realtime
I20150824-20:04:30.237(-7)? { calc_tag_id: 133,
I20150824-20:04:30.237(-7)?   calc_ts_update_hour: { '$gt': '2015-08-24   15:00:00' } }
I20150824-20:04:30.237(-7)? { calc_ts_update_hour: 1, calc_tag_id: 1, values: 1 }
I20150824-20:04:30.269(-7)? Calcs realtime
I20150824-20:04:30.269(-7)? { calc_tag_id: 134,
I20150824-20:04:30.269(-7)?   calc_ts_update_hour: { '$gt': '2015-08-24 15:00:00' } }
I20150824-20:04:30.269(-7)? { calc_ts_update_hour: 1, calc_tag_id: 1, values: 1 }
I20150824-20:04:30.307(-7)? Calcs realtime
I20150824-20:04:30.308(-7)? { calc_tag_id: 135,
I20150824-20:04:30.308(-7)?   calc_ts_update_hour: { '$gt': '2015-08-24 15:00:00' } }
I20150824-20:04:30.308(-7)? { calc_ts_update_hour: 1, calc_tag_id: 1, values: 1 }
I20150824-20:04:30.328(-7)? Calcs realtime
I20150824-20:04:30.328(-7)? { calc_tag_id: 136,
I20150824-20:04:30.329(-7)?   calc_ts_update_hour: { '$gt': '2015-08-24 15:00:00' } }
I20150824-20:04:30.329(-7)? { calc_ts_update_hour: 1, calc_tag_id: 1, values: 1 }
I20150824-20:04:30.348(-7)? Calcs realtime
I20150824-20:04:30.348(-7)? { calc_tag_id: 137,
I20150824-20:04:30.348(-7)?   calc_ts_update_hour: { '$gt': '2015-08-24 15:00:00' } }
I20150824-20:04:30.348(-7)? { calc_ts_update_hour: 1, calc_tag_id: 1, values: 1 }
I20150824-20:04:30.366(-7)? Calcs realtime
I20150824-20:04:30.366(-7)? { calc_tag_id: 138,
I20150824-20:04:30.367(-7)?   calc_ts_update_hour: { '$gt': '2015-08-24 15:00:00' } }
I20150824-20:04:30.367(-7)? { calc_ts_update_hour: 1, calc_tag_id: 1, values: 1 }
```

This is my entire autorun:

```
$meteor.autorun($scope, function() {
            $meteor.subscribe('site_topic_calc_data', {
                limit: parseInt($scope.getReactively('perPage')),
                skip: (parseInt($scope.getReactively('page')) - 1) *    parseInt($scope.getReactively('perPage')),
                sort: $scope.getReactively('sort')
            }, {'alert_site_id':      parseInt($stateParams.site_id)}).then(function() {
                $scope.site_calcs_count = $meteor.object(Counts     ,'number_of_calcs', false);
                $scope.site_services_count = $meteor.object(Counts ,'number_of_services', false);

                $scope.site_calcs.forEach( function(calc) {
                    console.log("Getting value information for calc tag " +   calc);
                    console.log("Getting calc current value from time series     data: " + calc.alert_id)
                    // console.log("Preparing current value query...");
                    var start_date = moment(new Date()).subtract(4, 'hours').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:00:00');
                    // console.log(start_date)
                    //used to go back five minutes just in case query false  within
                    var durationInMinutes = 5;
                    var value_minute = (new Date().getMinutes() - durationInMinutes);
                    console.log("Data hour: " + start_date.toString() + " data  minute: " + value_minute.toString() +
                        " for calc_id " + calc.alert_id);

                    var data_set = elephant_site_service_calcs_ts.find(
                        {
                            calc_tag_id: parseInt(calc.alert_id),
                            calc_ts_update_hour: start_date
                        });

                    console.log(data_set.fetch());

                    var calc_tag_data =          $meteor.collection(elephant_site_service_calcs_ts)
                        .subscribe('site_calcs_realtime',{
                            calc_ts_update_hour: 1,
                            calc_tag_id: 1,
                            values: 1
                        },
                        {
                            calc_tag_id: parseInt(calc.alert_id),
                            calc_ts_update_hour:
                            {
                                $gt:  start_date.toString()
                            }

                        });

                   console.log("Calc time series data " + calc_tag_data);

                    $scope.formatTagValue(calc_tag_data);

                });

                $scope.elephant_services.forEach( function (service_element) {
                    //get all tags

                    //do a foreach on each tag
                    //when clicked show graph popout
                    service_element.onClicked = function () {
                        //get service tags
                        console.log("Getting servers for service: " +  service_element.service);
                        var service_meta = service_server_dict_map.find({name: service_element.service});
                        console.log("Getting service: " + service_meta + "    server information for site id: " +
                            site_id);
                        $scope.get_service_site_servers(service_meta);
                        //go to tag_trend
                        //create tag list view t
                        //allows user to build a trend of all tags in service
                        //$state.go('tag_trend_details', {calc_id: calc._id});
                    };
                });
            });
        });
```

Please advise why meteor is not returning the results to the autorun as expected. When I comment out the find on the server side and add a fetch the results are as expected. The problem is the dataset is not being return to the frontend at all.

One last thing. Router:

```
.state('site_status',
            {
                url:'/site_status/:site_id/:site_name',
                          templateUrl:'client/elephant_heard_view/view/elephantProcess.ng.html',
                controller:'elephant_site_server_service_stats_ctrl',
                resolve:
                {
                    'subscribe':
                        [
                            "$meteor", function($meteor)
                        {
                            return $meteor.subscribe('site_topic_calc_data');
                        },

                        ],
                    'subscribe':
                        [
                            '$meteor', function($meteor)
                        {
                            return $meteor.subscribe('site_calcs_realtime');
                        }
                        ],
                    'subscribe':
                        [
                            '$meteor', function($meteor)
                        {
                            return $meteor.subscribe('site_servers');
                        }
                        ],
                    'subscribe':
                        [
                            '$meteor', function($meteor)
                        {
                            return $meteor.subscribe('site_tags');
                        }
                        ],
                    'subscribe':
                        [
                            '$meteor', function($meteor)
                        {
                            return elephant_site_service_calcs_ts.find();
                        }
                        ]
                }
            })
```

collection is defined in the model

```
elephant_site_service_calcs_ts = new Mongo.Collection("elephant_calc_evalv_ts");
```

Comment: could you please reduce your question to just the essential parts to reproduce the error? It is very long and as it stands, not very pointed.

Comment: can you show the code where you define the collection? have you debugged on the server using `meteor shell`?

Comment: collection is defined in the mod  elelephant_site_service_calcs_ts = new Mongo.Collection("elephant_calc_evalv_ts");

Comment: I believe all parts are relevant as they display process and results or lack there of from the code functions.